# improvement of a method to resize featured image?

Tags: java

I am working a method to resize featured image and I have finished it, but after testing seems something isn't right cause the image is deformed and don't look nice at all, I am looking very carefully, but I don't get to see what's the problem, I would really appreciate if you have any idea what is wrong or a better way to solve this. Have a look please, I would really need some better advice and thanks in advance!!

```
private byte[] resizeFeatureImage(MultipartFile featureImage)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(featureImage.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        double featImageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
        double featImageHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

        if (featImageHeight > MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT || featImageWidth > MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH)
        {
         // Sanity check on the input (division by zero, infinity):
            if (featImageWidth <= 1 || featImageHeight <= 1)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot do image resize for " + featureImage);
            }

            // The scaling factors to reach to max on WIDTH and HEIGHT:
            double xScale = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH   / featImageWidth;
            double yScale = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT  / featImageHeight;

            // Proportional (scale WIDTH and HEIGHT by the same factor):
            double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

            // (Possibly) Do not enlarge:
            scale = Math.min(1.0, scale);

            int finalWidth = Math.min((int) Math.round(scale * featImageWidth), MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH);
            int finalHeight = Math.min((int) Math.round(scale * featImageHeight), MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
            double ratio = featImageWidth / featImageHeight;
            // WIDTH is bigger then HEIGHT
            if (ratio > 1)
            {
                finalWidth = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH;
                finalHeight = (int) Math.round(MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT / ratio);
            }
            // HEIGHT is bigger then WIDTH
            else if (ratio < 1)
            {
                finalWidth = (int) Math.round(MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH / ratio);
                finalHeight = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
            }
            // WIDTH and HEIGHT are equal
            else
            {
                finalHeight = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
                finalWidth = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH;
            }

            logger.info("[resizeFeatureImage] [FEATURE IMAGE RESIZE] Starting to resize feature Image");
            Graphics2D g2d;
            BufferedImage resizedImage;

            if (featureImage.getContentType().contains("png"))
            {
                resizedImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            }
            else
            {
                resizedImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            }

            g2d = resizedImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.drawImage(ImageIO.read(featureImage.getInputStream()), 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight,
                    null);
            g2d.dispose();

            ImageIO.write(resizedImage, featureImage.getContentType().split("/")[1], baos);
            logger.info("[resizeFeatureImage] [FEATURE IMAGE RESIZE] Feature image resized!");
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        else
        {
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, featureImage.getContentType().split("/")[1], baos);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.warn("[resizeFeatureImage] [STATUS] - ERROR ");
        logger.warn("[resizeFeatureImage] [EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "The file you uploaded can be damaged or has incorrect encoding.");
    }
}
```

[image: first image]
[image: second]

Comment: What's exactly your problem ? Show us the deformed image for example

Comment: Ok I will post a photo that is deformed just in a min, the problem seems to be wrong resizing I don't what's the specif problem with the method, ok the images are there  @ArnaudClaudel

Comment: Sorry but I don't really see what's wrong with your images

Comment: In should have the same width as it is when is open for example.

Comment: Your using the wrong dimension in your scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scale, your image needs to retain the same ratio.

```
        double featImageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
        double featImageHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
        double ratio = featImageWidth/featImageHeight;             

        //this width meets your constraints
        int finalWidth = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH;

        //this final height is what the height would be to keep the same ratio.
        int finalHeight = (int)(finalWidth/ratio);

        if(finalHeight > MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT){
              //the height constrains the image.
              finalHeight = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
              finalWidth = (int)(finalHeight*ratio)
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to implement this, but I have a question,` scale = Math.min(1.0, scale);`
what is the value from the start, I mean the way I am getting is it good? @matt

Comment: @IliaTapia yes, the way you get scale is fine. I didn't follow too closely, but are you trying to scale the image to the maximum size it can fit?

Comment: yes, but without deformed it, and I am not sure if am I doing wrong, can you have a close look please, I would really appreciate that

Comment: what I want is to reduce image size within a limit (let's say height should not be more than Y and width should not be more than X), and we want to do it keeping the image original ratio (an image with original size 100x100 can become 20x20, 30x30, but never 30x50)

Comment: @IliaTapia I have updated the answer, you don't need a scale. Either the width will be the max width, or the height will be the max height. Whichever fits.

Comment: @IliaTapia yes I read your previous comment, I don't know why you ask me that. The code I provided scales the image to a confined region and keeps the same ratio. You can pretty much copy and paste it into the current code.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure, please understand me

Comment: @IliaTapia no worries, I thought you might have tried and had a specific reason to ask. Note, the part that keeps the ratio the same. One aspect (W,H) is calculated, then we use `ratio` to calculate the other aspect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197721/discussion-between-ilia-tapia-and-matt).